# How to migrate local db when using remote and local dbs in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I'm working with a local `mysql` db and a remote RDS AWS db. My `database.yml` is set up like so:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: requests
  username: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_username] %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_password] %>
  host: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_host] %>
  cast: false 
  port: 3306


development:
  aws:
    <<: *default
  local:
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8mb4
    database: tml_local 
    pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
    username: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:local_username] %>
    password: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:local_password] %>
    socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

I have 2 migration files for my local `mysql` db. I'm able to run `RAILS_ENV=development rails db:create:local` just fine but can't do the same with `migrate' to create the tables. Rails treats it like I'm trying to migrate the tables to the remote AWS db. What's the correct method to migrate tables for a local db?

Comment: What version of rails and ruby do you use?

Comment: I'm using Rails 6 and Ruby 2.6.3.

Comment: Did you happen to try 'rails db:migrate:local' and 'rails db:migrate:aws' for respective migrations? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#setting-up-your-application

Comment: I don't think I tried `rails db:migrate:local` without the explicit environment declaration but I did finally get the files to migrate by commenting out the `aws` portion of the `database.yml`. I'll try what you suggest in the future. Maybe it's just that simple.